# How to get Rollup's inline sourcemaps to work?

Tags: express, rollupjs

I am doing a rather strange thing where I am having express directly compile Javascript on every request (please pretend, for the moment, that this is a reasonable thing to do; needless to say, it is for internal development use only).

Unfortunately, though I have tried in several configurations, I cannot get sourcemaps to work.

My express route looks like this:

```
app.get(`/js/${f.script}`, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const bundle = await rollup.rollup({
      input: `./examples/src/${f.script}`,
      external: ['React', 'ReactDOM'],
      treeshake: false,
      plugins: [
        resolvePlugin({ jsnext: true, extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }),
        commonjsPlugin({ include: 'node_modules/**' }),
        babelPlugin({
          babelrc: false,
          presets: [
            [
              'env',
              { modules: false, targets: { browsers: ['last 2 versions'] } },
            ],
            'react',
          ],
          plugins: ['external-helpers', 'transform-class-properties'],
          exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        }),
      ],
    });

    const { code, map } = await bundle.generate({
      format: 'iife',
      sourcemap: 'inline',
      intro: `var process = {
        env : {
          NODE_ENV : 'development',
        }
      }`,
    });

    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    res.send(
      `${code}\n//@ sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8,${map}`,
    );
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`Served ${f.script}`);
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('oh bad no no', e);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

This gets me a script, followed by:

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8,{"version":3,"file":...
```

It's long, but it looks to my relatively untrained eye like a sourcemap. The browser completely ignores it.

I have tried this by just using `sourcemap: 'inline'` and none of the other bits, which appends no sourcemap to the end. I have now made several goes at manually 'tacking on' the generated sourcemap to the end of the script, but Chrome won't recognize it. Is there a simple syntax error here, or is my entire approach wrong?

Comment: The fact that `sourceMap: 'inline'` doesn't work is likely a Rollup bug: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/3913

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there — you're correct that you need to manually append a comment when using `bundle.generate` (it's done for you automatically if you use `bundle.write` instead, but that doesn't make sense here).

Most likely, the JSON is causing the data URI to be invalid, so it needs to be rendered as base64. There's a method attached to the `map` object that lets you do this easily:

```
res.send(
  `${code}\n//# sourceMappingURL=${map.toUrl()}`,
);
```

The implementation of `toUrl` can be seen [here](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/magic-string/blob/master/src/utils/SourceMap.js).

Note that I'm using `//#` instead of `//@` — both work, but `//#` is officially 'preferred' (the `//@` is a legacy artifact, according to the [spec](https://sourcemaps.info/spec.html)).